# Import and Export on User Style Files

Tags: macros

I have a near philosophical question now.  I am not a LaTeX programmer, but a LaTeX end user (writer).  I have a collection of LaTeX style files used for a pretty fancy book written in LaTeX.  My style files sometimes depend on macros in my other style files, and are exporting macros.  I sometimes want to test them out by themselves in a minimal example, too.

Right now, my plan is to reorganize my style files as follows:

At the top of each style file, say a `question.sty` file, I first put the required imports

```
\ProvidesPackage{question}[2022/04/01]

%% imports
\usepackage{xcolor} %% standard TL

\ProvideDocumentEnvironment{ threecolumn }%% my own macro hack facility, from elsewhere
  { \begin{center}\color{red} begin threecolumn \end{center} }
  { \begin{center}\color{red} end threecolumn \end{center} }
```

Having a stub will allow me to test out this stylefile in a simple tex file by itself, even though in its fancier forms it will use the `threecolumn` environment from elsewhere.  Then, this would be followed by what this style file actually provides for quick reference without delving into the implementation details.

```
%% exports
\ProvideDocumentCommand{\question}{ O{red} m }{}
```

(edit --- david carlisel suggested rightly that the above should probably better be a `\NewDocumentCommand`)

This will be followed by longer documentation, a changelog, etc.  Sort of like a 'pod' (perl).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%% question.sty
%%%
%%% this provides a nicely formatted question macro,
%%% with one argument blah blah blah
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Finally, I have the actual implementation, typically messy and cobbled together magic from lots of help that I have received on tex.stackexchange over the years (half of which I do not understand, all of which I highly appreciate).

```
\RenewDocumentCommand{\question}{ O{red}m }{
    \begin{threecolumn}
         \textcolor{#1.} #2
    \end{threecolumn}
}
```

Any other macros than `\question` should probably have a '@' in them, and require `\makeatletter`.

1. Is this a good plan?
2. Is this reinventing the wheel or ignoring useful existing latex style facilities for end-users/writers like myself?

Comment: your `onecolumn` definition will do nothing as `\onecolumn` is already defined.

Comment: bad example of mine.  will fix to call it \threecolumn...

Answer (score 1):

I see no advantage in having the `\ProvideDocumenCommand` it just makes things slower and is of dubious documentation value. It also completely masks package clashes with your package and existing code from other packages.

If your package intends to define a new `\question` command, then if you do the natural form

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{ O{red}m }{% don't forget %
    \begin{onecolumn}%
         \textcolor{#1.} #2%
    \end{onecolumn}%
}
```

Then if you accidentally have loaded some other code into the document that has already defined this, you get an error and can adjust the package loading.

However your `\Provide..` `\Renew...` combination will always silently over-ride the existing definition with no warning. It's like using `\def` and negates all the checking done by LaTeX's `\New...` definition forms

Comment: I like the idea of having an easy reference to all exported commands at the top, but I think you rightly point out that this should probably be a \NewDocumentCommand.  thanks.  come to think of it, how do I then deal with multiple inclusions of the same sty file, aka C's `ifndef header.hh`?